# Can you use Nameof, or another technique, to embed a procedure name in a code comment dynamically?

Tags: c#, vb.net

The following comment line becomes inaccurate if the name of SampelSubName gets changed. 
'This is a code comment about SampleSubName.

Comment: Afaik you can't. But after changing you can replace text in your code, using editor's replace function. But why have your method/procedure name on comments in first place?

Comment: You can't in just regular comments through code.  In [XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/documenting-your-code-with-xml), you can use a `cref` attribute to link to a compiler-verified type or member name, which will be updated if you change that name later.

Answer (score 10):

If you use Visual Studio 2015 or newer, renaming a method using the built-in refactoring tools will also rename any references in XML comments. You can refer to the method name using a `<see>` tag, e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a code comment about <see cref="SampelSubName" />.
/// </summary>
public void SampelSubName() { }
```

Comment: I think it's broadly similar but the OP appears to be using VB, not C# (unhelpfully they tagged both but when I went in to edit the question it was clear that the "following comment line" was a comment starting with a `'`, not a C# style comment.

Answer (score 10):

Another technique. Visual Studio IDE supports XML comments, like this:

```
/// <remarks>This is a code comment about <see cref="SampelSubName"/>. </remarks>
```

If you'll write comments like this and rename SampelSubName into something else, the IDE will also update these `cref=` reference.

For more information on XML comments, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments).